# I've been getting many BSOD crashes when encoding videos

Tags: windows, windows-10, hardware-failure, crash, desktop-computer

I've been getting many BSOD crashes when encoding videos. This is the information that I got from the Reliability History

```
Source
Windows

Summary
Shut down unexpectedly

Date
‎5/‎16/‎2022 9:17 PM

Status
Not reported

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: BlueScreen
Code:   124
Parameter 1:    0
Parameter 2:    ffff840625bb7028
Parameter 3:    be000000
Parameter 4:    800400
OS version: 10_0_19044
Service Pack:   0_0
Product:    768_1
OS Version: 10.0.19044.2.0.0.768.101
Locale ID:  1033
```

Comment: You should use WinDBG to analyze the dump file and provide us those additional details

Comment: That could be anything from hardware to driver problems. Check for temp, power, ram errors and updated drivers (especially GPU if you use that for encoding)  first, then start switching out components one at a time.

Comment: Monitor your temperatures when encoding using something like HWMonitor. If you can reliably make it crash at a certain temperature then it's probably a temperature issue. If not then your power supply might be failing and cannot deliver consistent power to run your computer at full-tilt. How old is your computer? What hardware does it have? Is it clean? Is your Windows installation fairly bug-free or do you get random error messages that you ignore?

Answer (score 8):

Overheat or under-power. Really hard to tell the difference on so little info. If you're software encoding, overheat is more likely. If GPU, that increases the possibility of under-power, but doesn't remove that it's still overheat.

First step would be to take it apart & clean out the dust bunnies.
If you're over-clocking anything, revert to defaults & let the system manage its own throttling.